# PortAudio mic picking up audio from speaker

Tags: c, audio, portaudio

I have the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "portaudio.h"

/* #define SAMPLE_RATE  (17932) // Test failure to open with this value. */
#define SAMPLE_RATE  (44100)
#define FRAMES_PER_BUFFER (512)
#define NUM_SECONDS     (5)
#define NUM_CHANNELS    (2)
/* #define DITHER_FLAG     (paDitherOff) */
#define DITHER_FLAG     (0) /**/
/** Set to 1 if you want to capture the recording to a file. */
#define WRITE_TO_FILE   (0)

/* Select sample format. */
#if 1
#define PA_SAMPLE_TYPE  paFloat32
typedef float SAMPLE;
#define SAMPLE_SILENCE  (0.0f)
#define PRINTF_S_FORMAT "%.8f"
#elif 1
#define PA_SAMPLE_TYPE  paInt16
typedef short SAMPLE;
#define SAMPLE_SILENCE  (0)
#define PRINTF_S_FORMAT "%d"
#elif 0
#define PA_SAMPLE_TYPE  paInt8
typedef char SAMPLE;
#define SAMPLE_SILENCE  (0)
#define PRINTF_S_FORMAT "%d"
#else
#define PA_SAMPLE_TYPE  paUInt8
typedef unsigned char SAMPLE;
#define SAMPLE_SILENCE  (128)
#define PRINTF_S_FORMAT "%d"
#endif

typedef struct
{
    int          frameIndex;  /* Index into sample array. */
    int          maxFrameIndex;
    SAMPLE      *recordedSamples;
}
paTestData;

/* This routine will be called by the PortAudio engine when audio is needed.
** It may be called at interrupt level on some machines so don't do anything
** that could mess up the system like calling malloc() or free().
*/
static int recordCallback( const void *inputBuffer, void *outputBuffer,
                           unsigned long framesPerBuffer,
                           const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo* timeInfo,
                           PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags,
                           void *userData )
{
    paTestData *data = (paTestData*)userData;
    const SAMPLE *rptr = (const SAMPLE*)inputBuffer;
    SAMPLE *wptr = &data->recordedSamples[data->frameIndex * NUM_CHANNELS];
    long framesToCalc;
    long i;
    int finished;
    unsigned long framesLeft = data->maxFrameIndex - data->frameIndex;

    (void) outputBuffer; /* Prevent unused variable warnings. */
    (void) timeInfo;
    (void) statusFlags;
    (void) userData;

    if( framesLeft < framesPerBuffer )
    {
        framesToCalc = framesLeft;
        finished = paComplete;
    }
    else
    {
        framesToCalc = framesPerBuffer;
        finished = paContinue;
    }

    if( inputBuffer == NULL )
    {
        for( i=0; i<framesToCalc; i++ )
        {
            *wptr++ = SAMPLE_SILENCE;  /* left */
            if( NUM_CHANNELS == 2 ) *wptr++ = SAMPLE_SILENCE;  /* right */
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for( i=0; i<framesToCalc; i++ )
        {
            *wptr++ = *rptr++;  /* left */
            if( NUM_CHANNELS == 2 ) *wptr++ = *rptr++;  /* right */
        }
    }
    data->frameIndex += framesToCalc;
    return finished;
}

/* This routine will be called by the PortAudio engine when audio is needed.
** It may be called at interrupt level on some machines so don't do anything
** that could mess up the system like calling malloc() or free().
*/
static int playCallback( const void *inputBuffer, void *outputBuffer,
                         unsigned long framesPerBuffer,
                         const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo* timeInfo,
                         PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags,
                         void *userData )
{
    paTestData *data = (paTestData*)userData;
    SAMPLE *rptr = &data->recordedSamples[data->frameIndex * NUM_CHANNELS];
    SAMPLE *wptr = (SAMPLE*)outputBuffer;
    unsigned int i;
    int finished;
    unsigned int framesLeft = data->maxFrameIndex - data->frameIndex;

    (void) inputBuffer; /* Prevent unused variable warnings. */
    (void) timeInfo;
    (void) statusFlags;
    (void) userData;

    if( framesLeft < framesPerBuffer )
    {
        /* final buffer... */
        for( i=0; i<framesLeft; i++ )
        {
            *wptr++ = *rptr++;  /* left */
            if( NUM_CHANNELS == 2 ) *wptr++ = *rptr++;  /* right */
        }
        for( ; i<framesPerBuffer; i++ )
        {
            *wptr++ = 0;  /* left */
            if( NUM_CHANNELS == 2 ) *wptr++ = 0;  /* right */
        }
        data->frameIndex += framesLeft;
        finished = paComplete;
    }
    else
    {
        for( i=0; i<framesPerBuffer; i++ )
        {
            *wptr++ = *rptr++;  /* left */
            if( NUM_CHANNELS == 2 ) *wptr++ = *rptr++;  /* right */
        }
        data->frameIndex += framesPerBuffer;
        finished = paContinue;
    }
    return finished;
}

/*******************************************************************/
int main(void);
int main(void)
{
    PaStreamParameters  inputParameters,
                        outputParameters;
    PaStream*           stream;
    PaError             err = paNoError;
    paTestData          data;
    int                 i;
    int                 totalFrames;
    int                 numSamples;
    int                 numBytes;
    SAMPLE              max, val;
    double              average;

    printf("patest_record.c\n"); fflush(stdout);

    data.maxFrameIndex = totalFrames = NUM_SECONDS * SAMPLE_RATE; /* Record for a few seconds. */
    data.frameIndex = 0;
    numSamples = totalFrames * NUM_CHANNELS;
    numBytes = numSamples * sizeof(SAMPLE);
    data.recordedSamples = (SAMPLE *) malloc( numBytes ); /* From now on, recordedSamples is initialised. */
    if( data.recordedSamples == NULL )
    {
        printf("Could not allocate record array.\n");
        goto done;
    }
    for( i=0; i<numSamples; i++ ) data.recordedSamples[i] = 0;

    err = Pa_Initialize();
    if( err != paNoError ) goto done;

    inputParameters.device = Pa_GetDefaultInputDevice(); /* default input device */
    if (inputParameters.device == paNoDevice) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error: No default input device.\n");
        goto done;
    }
    inputParameters.channelCount = 2;                    /* stereo input */
    inputParameters.sampleFormat = PA_SAMPLE_TYPE;
    inputParameters.suggestedLatency = Pa_GetDeviceInfo( inputParameters.device )->defaultLowInputLatency;
    inputParameters.hostApiSpecificStreamInfo = NULL;

    /* Record some audio. -------------------------------------------- */
    err = Pa_OpenStream(
              &stream,
              &inputParameters,
              NULL,                  /* &outputParameters, */
              SAMPLE_RATE,
              FRAMES_PER_BUFFER,
              paClipOff,      /* we won't output out of range samples so don't bother clipping them */
              recordCallback,
              &data );
    if( err != paNoError ) goto done;

    err = Pa_StartStream( stream );
    if( err != paNoError ) goto done;
    printf("\n=== Now recording!! Please speak into the microphone. ===\n"); fflush(stdout);

    while( ( err = Pa_IsStreamActive( stream ) ) == 1 )
    {
        Pa_Sleep(1000);
        printf("index = %d\n", data.frameIndex ); fflush(stdout);
    }
    if( err < 0 ) goto done;

    err = Pa_CloseStream( stream );
    if( err != paNoError ) goto done;

    /* Measure maximum peak amplitude. */
    max = 0;
    average = 0.0;
    for( i=0; i<numSamples; i++ )
    {
        val = data.recordedSamples[i];
        if( val < 0 ) val = -val; /* ABS */
        if( val > max )
        {
            max = val;
        }
        average += val;
    }

    average = average / (double)numSamples;

    printf("sample max amplitude = "PRINTF_S_FORMAT"\n", max );
    printf("sample average = %lf\n", average );

    /* Write recorded data to a file. */
#if WRITE_TO_FILE
    {
        FILE  *fid;
        fid = fopen("recorded.raw", "wb");
        if( fid == NULL )
        {
            printf("Could not open file.");
        }
        else
        {
            fwrite( data.recordedSamples, NUM_CHANNELS * sizeof(SAMPLE), totalFrames, fid );
            fclose( fid );
            printf("Wrote data to 'recorded.raw'\n");
        }
    }
#endif

    /* Playback recorded data.  -------------------------------------------- */
    data.frameIndex = 0;

    outputParameters.device = Pa_GetDefaultOutputDevice(); /* default output device */
    if (outputParameters.device == paNoDevice) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error: No default output device.\n");
        goto done;
    }
    outputParameters.channelCount = 2;                     /* stereo output */
    outputParameters.sampleFormat =  PA_SAMPLE_TYPE;
    outputParameters.suggestedLatency = Pa_GetDeviceInfo( outputParameters.device )->defaultLowOutputLatency;
    outputParameters.hostApiSpecificStreamInfo = NULL;

    printf("\n=== Now playing back. ===\n"); fflush(stdout);
    err = Pa_OpenStream(
              &stream,
              NULL, /* no input */
              &outputParameters,
              SAMPLE_RATE,
              FRAMES_PER_BUFFER,
              paClipOff,      /* we won't output out of range samples so don't bother clipping them */
              playCallback,
              &data );
    if( err != paNoError ) goto done;

    if( stream )
    {
        err = Pa_StartStream( stream );
        if( err != paNoError ) goto done;
        
        printf("Waiting for playback to finish.\n"); fflush(stdout);

        while( ( err = Pa_IsStreamActive( stream ) ) == 1 ) Pa_Sleep(100);
        if( err < 0 ) goto done;
        
        err = Pa_CloseStream( stream );
        if( err != paNoError ) goto done;
        
        printf("Done.\n"); fflush(stdout);
    }

done:
    Pa_Terminate();
    if( data.recordedSamples )       /* Sure it is NULL or valid. */
        free( data.recordedSamples );
    if( err != paNoError )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "An error occured while using the portaudio stream\n" );
        fprintf( stderr, "Error number: %d\n", err );
        fprintf( stderr, "Error message: %s\n", Pa_GetErrorText( err ) );
        err = 1;          /* Always return 0 or 1, but no other return codes. */
    }
    return err;
}
```

This can also be found here: http://files.portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/paex__record_8c_source.html

I noticed when I started recording section, if I have something playing on my speaker, portaudio will pick up that sound as well. Is there anyway to configure port audio not to pick up that sound?

Comment: Please include a [mre] here instead of an external link that will break.  If your microphone is picking up the audio the answer is sound isolation (placement of microphone in relation to source, or using headphones) and it would be off-topic.  If it's an internally routed would it be a software issue suitable for here.

Comment: So for my specific use case I'd like to allow for sound to come out of the speakers at the same time as I am recording from the mic and for pulseaudio to ignore the sound coming from the speakers

Comment: You could subtract the audio you are playing from your recording.  I don't know how or if that works in practice.  Good luck (and good job on updating the question).

Comment: What you are looking for is something called [Acoustic Echo Cancellation (AEC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echo_suppression_and_cancellation). It is a very difficult algorithm to get right in software. Given the rigid timing requirements of tracking the speaker output and microphone in sync together, some implementations run in kernel more near the audio drivers.  I'm not certain if any of the Linux audio services  a built in AEC, but a quick Internet search suggestions some open source projects are out there.

Comment: There's also some AEC code in the WebRTC stack. https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/refs/heads/main/modules/audio_processing/